# How to create a search box for multiple columns?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I'm new to PowerApps - I'm attempting to build an app that s that filters on the logged-in user and also allows the user to search within his/her assigned facilities.

If I use this CM_Email=vCurrentUser.Email then I get my assigned facilites but I'm stuck on adding the other criteria

```
(CM_Email=vCurrentUser.Email) &&
StartsWith(SCID, TextSearchBox_2.Text) 
|| StartsWith(CITY, TextSearchBox_2.Text)
|| StartsWith(STORE_NAME, TextSearchBox_2.Text)
)
```

If I have 20 facilities assigned to me and I want the ability to search for the facility in XYZ city or if I know the SCID and can search for it or I can search for the Store_name

Comment: If so, post it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with

```
Filter(xRef_Hierarchy,(CM_Email=vCurrentUser.Email) && (StartsWith(SCID, TextSearchBox_2.Text) || StartsWith(STORE_NAME, TextSearchBox_2.Text) || StartsWith(CITY, TextSearchBox_2.Text)) )
```